# BackBone - best way to send a server request

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone and am just getting familiar with it.
I have a model and a collection - and view to the collection and a Form.
I'm sending request to get/get all/create by doing form.submit(), or something similar - which calls for the correct type [GET/POST/PUT] to the server using the base URL in the collection/model.
how do i send a non-trivial request?  say that my base URL is /some/url , and i want to send /some/url/doSomething.  should i directly send an ajax request with this URL or does backbone handle this in a more simpler way?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to define the url of the backend resource on the bb model or collection and call the corresponding methods on an instance of the model / collection (fetch, save, destroy);

Answer (score 1):

In backbone, you can pass `url` as an option to your `model.fetch`, `model.save` requests, etc to override the default declared in the model. You don't need to manually form an ajax request with `$.ajax` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

If your URL does not pertain to a particular resource/model/collection, you may use raw jQuery ajax requests.

```
$.ajax({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/some/url',
     success: function(resp) { //handle response}
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

Best example of REST API is [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/)

example of merge a pull request (Merge Button):

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/merge
```

The main goal is using resources instead a commands. For example:

REST:

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/merge
{"commit_message":"mesg"}
```

NO-REST:

```
POST /merge
{"commit_message": "mesg", "owner": 123, "repo":"asd", "number": 1}
```

Cheers